# Change to xth directory terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, ls

Is there a way in a unix shell (specifically Ubuntu) to change directory into the xth directory that was printed from the ls command?
I know you can sort a directory in multiple ways, but using the output from ls to get the xth directory?

An example shell:

```
$ ls
$ first_dir second_dir third_really_long_and_complex_dir
```

where I want to move into the third_really_long_and_complex_dir by passing 3 (or 2 in proper array format).
I know I could simply copy and paste, but if I'm already using the keyboard, it would be easier to type something like "cdls 2" or something like that if I knew the index.

**UPDATE**

For anyone still seeing this, I created this question back when I was really new to linux/bash and didn't realise there was such a thing as tab-completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with `cd` in an interactive session is that you generally want to change the current directory of the shell that is processing the command prompt. That means that launching a sub-shell (e.g. a script) would not help, since any `cd` calls would not affect the parent shell.

Depending on which shell you are using, however, you might be able to define a *function* to do this. For example in bash:

```
function cdls() {
    # Save the current state of the nullglob option
    SHOPT=`shopt -p nullglob`

    # Make sure that */ expands to nothing when no directories are present
    shopt -s nullglob

    # Get a list of directories
    DIRS=(*/)

    # Restore the nullblob option state
    $SHOPT

    # cd using a zero-based index
    cd "${DIRS[$1]}"
}
```

Note that in this example I absolutely refuse to parse the output of `ls`, [for a number of reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead I let the shell itself retrieve a list of directories (or links to directories)...

That said, I suspect that using this function (or anything to this effect) is a very good way to set yourself up for an enormous mess - like using `rm` after changing to the wrong directory. File-name auto-completion is dangerous enough already, without forcing yourself to *count*...

Comment: This works brilliantly on my system. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I have a function for this:

```
   function cdi. {
       IFS=$'\n'
       PAGE=${1:-1}
       LPP=${2:-11}
       first=$(( 1 + LPP * PAGE - LPP ))
       last=$(( LPP * PAGE ))
       select cd_into in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n" |\
             sed -n $first,${last}p);
       do
           EXIT=-1;
           if [[ $REPLY == n ]]; then let PAGE=PAGE+1; cdi. $PAGE $LPP ; EXIT=$?
         elif [[ $REPLY == p ]]; then let PAGE=PAGE-1; cdi. $PAGE $LPP ; EXIT=$?
         elif [[ $REPLY == m ]]; then let LPP=LPP*2;   cdi. $PAGE $LPP ; EXIT=$?
         elif [[ $REPLY == l ]]; then let LPP=LPP/2;   cdi. $PAGE $LPP ; EXIT=$?
         elif [[ $REPLY == q || $REPLY == 0 ]];then return 0; fi

           if [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]; then return 0; fi

           cd_into=${cd_into//\~/$HOME}
           if [ -d "$cd_into" ];then
               cd "$cd_into"; return 0; else
               echo "oops! \`$cd_into' is not a folder (?)"
           fi
       done
       unset IFS
   }
```

To use:

```
$ cdi.
1) .mozilla.new      3) .swt             5) tmp              7) .vim             9) .ssh
2) .crack-attack     4) Downloads        6) .Eterm           8) .frozen-bubble  10) .irssi
Which #?:
```